# Tracert command with lots of routers on way - CMD

Tags: networking, command-line

Our computers are placed in a Local Area Network, recently I found a significant reduction in web browsing speed, when I did a `tracert google.com` encountered with results below:

```
Tracing route to google.com [173.194.45.6]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    39 ms     *       46 ms  10.0.0.100
  2    46 ms     *       46 ms  192.168.231.131
  3    46 ms     *       46 ms  10.51.116.1
  4    46 ms    62 ms     *     217.218.181.193
  5    46 ms     *       46 ms  217.218.189.225
  6   593 ms   624 ms   671 ms  217.218.189.186
  7   577 ms   531 ms   546 ms  10.10.53.117
  8   531 ms   499 ms   499 ms  10.10.36.117
  9   437 ms   468 ms   452 ms  10.10.53.109
 10   624 ms   577 ms   531 ms  nyk-b7-link.telia.net [213.248.99.177]
 11   406 ms   359 ms   359 ms  nyk-b5-link.telia.net [80.91.252.51]
 12   453 ms   499 ms   437 ms  nyk-bb1-link.telia.net [213.155.130.246]
 13   437 ms   437 ms   421 ms  kbn-bb1-link.telia.net [213.155.134.51]
 14   484 ms   452 ms   468 ms  s-bb3-link.telia.net [213.155.134.178]
 15   468 ms   452 ms   468 ms  s-b3-link.telia.net [213.155.133.99]
 16   406 ms   374 ms   359 ms  72.14.212.90
 17   421 ms   421 ms   468 ms  216.239.43.246
 18   515 ms   531 ms   609 ms  209.85.241.192
 19   531 ms   515 ms   515 ms  66.249.95.132
 20   749 ms   765 ms   859 ms  209.85.240.29
 21   937 ms   968 ms  1015 ms  209.85.253.197
 22   999 ms  1015 ms  1015 ms  209.85.252.45
 23  1092 ms  1077 ms  1062 ms  209.85.254.70
 24  1077 ms  1174 ms  1156 ms  lis01s06-in-f6.1e100.net [173.194.45.6]

Trace complete.
```

Is it really normal?

Comment: is this at your work and you are responsible for systems administration or is it a private/home issue?

Comment: @Znau, I'm a computer end user not the administrator

Comment: if you have someone responsible for sys/network administration let them know of that tracert; you may be behind a VPN/proxy. if you can handle it accordingly to the company policy, check your proxy settings and place them on direct/no proxy and your hosts file.

Comment: The number of hops seems reasonable, the latency doesn't. For comparision: [Edit] I tested two traceroutes to google.com from two different computers (from home and from uni).  Both show 13 hops and 16 ms until they reach they local google.  (local since I am assuming CDN).

Comment: Asking if this is normal is not really a good question. Normal could be different for lots of different people. For instance - if I traceroute from home, I will have one internal hop (my router) then make it to google.com in 13 hops. However, at work there are more internal hops; which is normal. If you work at an ISP there will probably be very few hops; which will be normal. So a better question would be to let us know of a change that happened that resulted in slow browsing, or give us more information about your network (might be illegal). Alternatively, ask you netadmins! They will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong. It's not ideal either. It may very well be "normal" for your network. Understanding where the latencies come from and why they are there isn't always easy. This [presentation](http://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog47/presentations/Sunday/RAS_Traceroute_N47_Sun.pdf) is worth the read. It will give you some idea why you could be getting these results.

Looking at the response times a couple of things are clear. First, The device at hop 6 (217.218.189.186) adds a lot of latency. It is responsible for almost all of the latency between it and hop 19 (66.249.95.132). You can see that many of the response times up to hop 19 are actually less than the values at hop 6. Second, from hop 20 onward the response time starts growing again from hop to hop.

The number of hops seems reasonable, as the other comments state, though it's on the higher side of "normal".